# Trying to get Provider typings right

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get the Provider typings for the following right:

```js
interface IAuthContext {
  auth: {
    user: IUser | null
    authenticated: boolean
  }
  logout: () => Promise<void>
}

const logout = useCallback(
  () =>
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/logout").then(() =>
      setAuth({ user: null, authenticated: false })
    ),
  []
)

const memo = useMemo(
  () => ({
    auth,
    setAuth,
  }),
  [auth, setAuth]
)
```

The problem is here

```js
return (
  <authContext.Provider value={[memo, logout]}>
```

```
Type '((() => Promise<void>) | { auth: { user: null; authenticated: boolean; }; setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ user: null; authenticated: boolean; }>>; })[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IAuthContext': auth, logout
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: The type of `value` prop should match `IAuthContext` interface. However you are passing `[memo, logout]` which is different.

Comment: How is this usually fixed? since `memo` returns the interface except for logout, I am not sure if I have to change the interface or change the way I pass in the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because `value` prop does not match `IAuthContext` interface. You  are passing an array of two objects `[memo, logout]` which is not correct. You need to pass an object of a shape `{auth, logout}`. I don't know how your code looks like, but I assume it is similar to the code below. I changed the `memo` and also fixed the `value` prop.

```
interface IAuthContext {
    auth: {
        user: string | null;
        authenticated: boolean;
    };
    logout: () => Promise<void>;
}

const authContext = React.createContext<IAuthContext>(null);

const Test: React.FC = () => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState<IAuthContext['auth']>(/*someInitialValue*/);

    const logout = useCallback(
        () => fetch('http://localhost:4000/logout').then(() => setAuth({ user: null, authenticated: false })),
        []
    );

    const memo = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            ...auth,
        };
    }, [auth]);

    return <authContext.Provider value={{ auth: memo, logout }}>BLAH</authContext.Provider>;
};
```